# How to query the local database when using Microsoft sync framework offline?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have an application built on Microsoft's Sync Framework. Data is entered and stored in database configured with the sync framework wizard. From what I understand, this puts a clone of the server database in a local directory and the database version is SQL Compact edition.

The user will on occasion use the application offline and will need information from one database in order to fill another. They will select a tool from the Tools database and a device with certain parameters from the device database. In order to do this I need to be able to query the local database when offline.

First I attempted to fill my comboboxes by using the local ConnectionString from my settings.

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ClientDatabaseConnectionString)
conn.Open()
Dim dat As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Distinct InstrumentType FROM CreateScriptTable", conn)
Dim dt As New DataSet
dat.Fill(dt, "TestScriptTable")
cbInst.DataSource = dt.Tables("TestScriptTable").DefaultView
cbInst.DisplayMember = "InstrumentType"
cbInst.ValueMember = "InstrumentType"
```

Next as it is an SQL ce datbase I used the SQLCeConnection:

```
Dim conn As SqlCeConnection
conn = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TestsDatabase4.sdf;Max Database Size=2047")
Dim dat As SqlCeDataAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT Distinct InstrumentType FROM TestScriptTable", conn)
Dim dt As New DataSet
dat.Fill(dt, "TestScriptTable")
cbInst.DataSource = dt.Tables("TestScriptTable").DefaultView
cbInst.DisplayMember = "InstrumentType"
cbInst.ValueMember = "InstrumentType"
```

Various formats for the local connection string were passed into SQLConnection() including removing `Max Database Size=2047`
Neither of these approaches worked so I tried to change the connection string at runtime following the tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc307956.aspx)
This did not work either so at the moment I am unable to retrieve any data at will offline. 
Has anyone any thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: Error message? Provide the full path to the database file in your connection string.

Comment: There is no error message but the Dataset is empty. I can query the remote server but when I query the local version I don't get any data. Won't the full path be relative to my machine therefore not working on another machine? I have tried this and it still results in an empty dataset.

Comment: if you're getting an error then its finding the database you specified on the connection string...have you checked that you're connecting to the correct database? check how many sdfs do you have in your project specially in the bin folder...

Comment: You were right I had some stray databases in the project - solved now, thank you.